# Use enterprise architect to export models with metadata

Tags: arcgis-desktop, metadata, arccatalog, schema-architecture, enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect to build a data model, and I need to know if there is a way to write somewhere in EA "in notes or glossary....." the description of each feature and class that I have in my diagram (like metadata) so when I export the model as XML to arc  I would find the earlier description that I wrote using EA in ArcCatalog

Comment: If you can write metadata into a metadata repository (such as GeoNetwork) with a CSW service enabled, then you can access the metadata through the CSW in ArcCatalog.  This post seems to suggest that you can write metadata to a repo using EA https://community.sparxsystems.com/news/724-metadata-management-with-enterprise-architect but not sure how to, or whether the repo can have a CSW attached...